# How to Use AWS Amplify react components anywhere in an application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify

I'm using aws-amplify and aws-amplify-react in my react application and I'm facing an authentication UI challenge that seems simple but I can't figure it out.
Here is my App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Authenticator hideDefault={true}>
        <Router>
          <MyProvider>
            <Routes />
            <NavbarBot />
          </MyProvider>
        </Router>
      </Authenticator>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I've hidden the React authentication components that comes with Authenticator. However, I want to use them in a child component (Accounts) nested in one of my Routes.

Here are my Routes:

```
const paths = () =>{
    return(
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Splash} />
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/listing" component={Listing} />
            <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
        )
    };

const Routes =  withRouter(paths);
```

My Account component is blank. I tried importing the individual components like SignIn, SiginUp, and Greetings from `aws-amplify-react` and use them as jsx elements (e.g `<SignIn />`) but that doesn't render anything. Do I have to instantiate these components directly  within the `<Authenticator>` component in my `App.js`?  Do I have to pass down the components as props to my `Accounts` component? If so, is there a painless way to do so?

Maybe I am missing something, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want Authentication on the accounts page then you don't have to use `Authenticator` in the App component. Remove it and instead `import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react';` directly inside the accounts page and wrap the account page export as `export default withAuthenticator(Account);`

This will give you all the UI components you need only inside the accounts page. Change the account export to `export default withAuthenticator(Account, {includeGreetings: true});` to get a logout button as well. Other [config options here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#sign-in)

If you want to build you own UI and integrate it then import auth instead `import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';`, you don't get UI components but you can customise the behaviour however you want. More on how to use Auth [in the docs here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#sign-in)

Comment: If that didn't address your problem please clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is exactly the behavior I wanted. I didn't attempt this at first because I was afraid the rest of the application wouldn't share the signed in user/state but I just realized I can manage that myself.

Great answer, thanks!

Comment: hey @AdhamElBanhawy, how did you end up managing the login state outside of the Authenticator component?

Comment: Great that this helped Adham, but I don't think it answers the original question: How to use the Amplify provided `<SignIn />` component but not have it be a first-child of the `<App />` wrapped with `<Authenticator>`. I want two layouts for signedIn vs other authStates